# How can i change color (background and foreground) of my console application from another project in my solution C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, console-application

I have two projects, P1 (Main project, the .exe of app) and P2(My library with some helper methods and such, .dll file) in same solution and i need to change background color of the console (`Console.BackgroundColor`) and foreground color (`Console.ForegroundColor`) from there, but it didn't work. Yeah, i could just do it from P1 but there are several reasons that i can't.

```
//Function that changes color (i used it in my P1 and it worked)
public static void ChangeColors(ConsoleColor backgroundColor, ConsoleColor foregroundColor) 
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    Console.ForegroundColor = foregroundColor;
}
```

Comment: `but it didn't work.` Can we see what you have tried?

Comment: I tried doing Console.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor (parameter of my function) in P2

Comment: There might be something wrong on your side because it does work here, post a mini-example reproducing the error.

Comment: Pastebin of my function http://pastebin.com/jxj0j9Qq

Comment: If you defined your method in P2 and call it in P1 it would work. Are you sure there is new text being added to the screen after this method is called? It only affects new text.

Comment: @dukedukes will check when fix other things (namespace stuff and 60 errors) hah

Comment: @dukedukes Everything works but this part http://pastebin.com/eqqG7MB7 doesnt work, it says that color is changed to color that i want but it doesnt change

Comment: Just to clarify, is new text being printed after this method is ran? Existing text won't change. Also be aware of anything else in your program that could be changing the color back to what it was originally.

Comment: @dukedukes new text doesnt change color and ill check, but it works on other places but wont work here from some reason

Comment: And it says that background color is my wanted color, not black but i dont see it

Comment: It changes the background for the text that gets printed, not the whole background. Follow Aybe's advice and make a small example in a new application to play around with. That may show you what's going wrong in your main application.

Comment: I tried to type new text but it dont work, will try @Aybe's advice tommorow

Comment: @dukedukes theres nothing wrong in my code idk whats happening, this is my full code http://pastebin.com/mbaVa14V